# How to remotely delete an AD-Computer from Active Directory - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am running Powershell on a remote computer that is not connected to the domain, does not have any modules and is running PS 2.0.

I want to contact the Active Directory of my domain, check if there is an entry for this computer and; if yes, delete that entry.

Checking the AD via ADSI for existance of the computer is easy. However the deleting does not work somehow.

Here is my code so far:

```
# Variables
$domain = "Test.com"
$Ldap = "LDAP://$domain"
$Global:AdsiSearcher = $Null

# Function to Delete PC
Function DeleteThisPc ()
{
    $CurrentSearch = $Global:AdsiSearcher
    $One = $CurrentSearch.FindOne()
    $OPath = [adsi]$One.Path
    $OPath.psbase.DeleteTree()
```

The Problem lies here. Even though $OPath is of type `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` and the propertylist shows all properties, it does not allow me to delete the object.

> Exception calling "DeleteTree" with "0" argument(s): "Logon failure:
>   unknown user name or bad password.
>
> At C:\TEMP\Domjoin1.1.ps1:49 char:33 $OPath.psbase.DeleteTree <<<< ()
>   CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Code:

```
# Function to get a ADSISearcher and set it to the global-AdsiSearcher
Function ConnectAD ()
{
    $domain = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Ldap,"$domain\Bob",'1234')
    $filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(cn=$ComputerName))"
    $AdsiSearch = [adsisearcher]""
    $AdsiSearch.SearchRoot = $domain
    $AdsiSearch.Filter = $filter
    $Global:AdsiSearcher = $AdsiSearch
}

# Main Function
Function Sub_Check-ADComputer()
{
    ConnectAD
    $CurSearch = $Global:AdsiSearcher.findOne()
    if($CurSearch -ne $null)
    {
       DeleteThisPc
    }
}

# Start
Sub_Check-ADComputer
```

Even though the issue seems to be obvious as the error states:

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

The username and password is the same that I use to get the object from the AD in the first place. So it does work - do I somehow have to give the credentials again when trying to `deleteTree()` ? I also gave the User FullControl on the OU that the object is stored in.

Edit:

When I do it on another machine with PS 3.0 I get a different Error message:

> Exception calling "DeleteTree" with "0" argument(s): "Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

When using invoke command the variables are not transmitted unless specified by -argumentlist. Another approach I discovered was the following, which is the one I am using now and which works like a charm.

```
$domain = "DOMAINNAME"
$AdUser = "$domain\JoinDom"
$AdPW = "PASSWORD"
$AdPass = convertto-securestring -string $AdPW -AsPlainText -Force
$AdCred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdUser,$AdPass 
$ThisComputer = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
$RetValue = $true
Function CheckExist ()
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = ‘SilentlyContinue’
    $Ascriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("get-adcomputer $ThisComputer")
    $Ret = Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -ScriptBlock $Ascriptblock -Credential $AdCred    
    $ErrorActionPreference = ‘Continue’
    return $Ret
}
$ExistBefore = CheckExist
if($ExistBefore -ne $null)
{
        $scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("Remove-ADComputer $ThisComputer")
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -Credential $AdCred
        $ExistAfter = CheckExist
        if($ExistAfter -ne $null){$RetValue = $false}
}
if($RetValue -ne $false)
{
    Add-computer -domainname $domain -credential $Adcred -OUPath "OU=MyOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=DE"
    Restart-Computer -Force
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your domain controller runs Windows Server 2008 or higher you could leverage PowerShell sessions to avoid having to work with ADSI.
Just run the following command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName domaincontroller.test.com -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Then run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` to allow you to use `Get-ADComputer` and `Remove-ADComputer`.

Comment: This seems like a very good approach. Using my domain-Administrator account i was able to remotely run a script from outside the domain with this. Thank you! - One problem remains, that when using the service account I created, it does still give me an "Access is denied". Do you by any chance know which groups or rights that service account needs to run a script like this?

Comment: Your service account will need the create/delete computer objects right on the relevant organizational unit(s). You can use the "Delegation of control wizard" from the "Active Directory Users and Computers" management console. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732524.aspx